# Set Linux and Windows path in .NET/c# to create a log file

Tags: c#, .net, linux, path

I am trying to set a unified path for my .NET application.

Currently the path is hard coded for Windows. It looks like this:

```
var tempFilename = $@"C:\Logs\{ApplicationName}\RollingFile.log";
```

How can I create the path where it handles both linux and windows?

Comment: Maybe `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)`

Answer (score 0):

Use a special path like L.B said. Or run a check to see if you are running on linux.

```
int platformInt = (int)Environment.OSVersion.Platform;
if((p == 4) || (p == 6) || (p == 128))
{
    var tempFilename = $@"linuxpath"; 
}
```

This will detect if the computer is running Linux. Look [here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/technical/#how-to-detect-the-execution-platform) for more.